# Codeigniter multiple insert using radio button

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
HI  I NEED YOUR HELP.. 

I have this VIEW which show all items according to its company 

   <?php foreach($item_list as $item2):?>
    <tr>
     <input type = "hidden" name = "status[]" value ="5" >
     <td><input type = "text" name = "item_id[]" value ="<?php echo $item2->item_id ?>" ></td>
     <td><?php echo $item2->item_desc?></td>
     <td><?php echo $item2->serial_num ?></td>
     <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "JobStatus[]" value = "quotation" ></td>
     <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "JobStatus[]" value = "job order" ></td>                                    
     </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

---------------------------------------- html output ---------------------------------------

```
                             <tr>
     <input type = "hidden" name = "status[]" value ="5" >
   <td><input type = "text" name = "item_id[]" value ="146" ></td>
   <td>sample item 01</td>
   <td>123</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "JobStatus[]" value = "quotation" ></td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "JobStatus[]" value = "job order" ></td>                                     
 </tr>
                                 <tr>
     <input type = "hidden" name = "status[]" value ="5" >
   <td><input type = "text" name = "item_id[]" value ="147" ></td>
   <td>sample item 02</td>
   <td>21344</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "JobStatus[]" value = "quotation" ></td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "JobStatus[]" value = "job order" ></td>                                     
 </tr>
```

My problem is that I want to insert this to new value (status, item_id, item_desc, serial_num, JobStatus) to quotation table in mysql. If Click I on radio item_id 146 row it will insert all values under item_id 146 likewise to item_id 147 it will insert all item values under 147 item_id

Comment: This `" my problem is how to insert this value according to its item_id"` is the most vague question I've seen today. Please clarify it more so we can understand what you really want to do and actually ask the question.

Comment: Hi Darren sorry i will post again thank you

Comment: I have this item list with radio button. I would like to update this item if its for QUOTATION or FOR JOB ORDER. 

This item list actually is fetch from database (MYSQL).


![enter image description here][1]

 




MODEL: (when submit form)




  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/683DS.png

Comment: You want to update all the items in the loop simultaneously with a single call to backend? Is that what you want? Also you are using AJAX to send data to backend or form action?

Comment: HI nightgaunt yes i want to update this item in a single call to backend. Im not using any AJAX. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you want the radio button to be checked according to it's job status?????

If so, try something along these lines ( i don't know how your your database is set up so you will have to alter the following):

```
<?php foreach($query as $item):?>

<td><input type = "text" name = "item_id" value ="<?php echo $item->item_id ?>" ></td>
<td><?php echo $item->item_desc?></td>
<td><?php echo $item->serial_num ?></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="JobStatus" value="quotation" <?php $item->job_status == 'quotation' ? echo "checked" : null; ?> ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="JobStatus" value="job order" <?php $item->job_status == 'job order' ? echo "checked" : null; ?> ></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: hi Bollis thank you for the suggestion. Actually what i want is to update  this item if its for quotation or job status when submit.

Comment: You can use form input arrays. Basically you have the name of the input as item_id[] etc and then you can access it in the Php so that $_POST["item_id"] will be an array. Google "form input array" it will give you more information. Is this what you are after?

Comment: Hi Bollis ok i will try yourt suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Hi thank you all. I already solve my problem Thank you anyways for help

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the whole loop inside a `form` tag with `action="index.php/controller/method"`

In your controller,

```
public function method() {
    $items = $this->input->post('item_id', TRUE);
    $job_status = $this->input->post('JobStatus', TRUE);
    $stati = $this->input->post('status', TRUE);

    foreach($items as $key => $row) {
        $this->your_model->insert_new($row, $job_status[$key], $stati[$key]);
    }
}
```

In `your_model`, write the database query to insert these data wherever you need. Of course you need to change the names - `method`, `controller` and `your_model` to suit your application.

Comment: Hi nightgaunt thank you for the suggestion.. Ok will try this.. thank you